# Error when I go to create folder in dropbox php

Tags: php, dropbox

**When I go to create a folder it creates the problem is that it comes with the following error**

- you will need this composer run in terminal :composer require spatie/dropbox-api
- 

> Fatal error: Uncaught Spatie\Dropbox\Exceptions\BadRequest: from_lookup/not_found/... in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Form - No JavaScript\vendor\spatie\dropbox-api\src\Client.php:667 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Form - No JavaScript\vendor\spatie\dropbox-api\src\Client.php(656): Spatie\Dropbox\Client->determineException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Form - No JavaScript\vendor\spatie\dropbox-api\src\Client.php(100): Spatie\Dropbox\Client->rpcEndpointRequest('files/copy_v2', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Form - No JavaScript\dropbox.php(48): Spatie\Dropbox\Client->copy('Coisas', 'Teste1') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login Form - No JavaScript\vendor\spatie\dropbox-api\src\Client.php on line 667*

> The code I'm using is a code that creates folders with pre-established names so I used this code to get the name field and create a folder when the button is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Coding By CodingNepal - youtube.com/codingnepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animated Login Form | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <div class="center">
        
        <div class="dropbox"><img src="dropbox.png" width="90" height="90" ></div>
      <form method="post">
        <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="text" required  name="foldername">
          <span></span>
          <label>Digite o Nome da Pasta</label>
        </div>
        
          
        <input type="submit" value="Criar Pasta" name="submit">
        <div class="signup_link">
          Anexar Arquivo? <a href="#">Clique aqui</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Spatie\Dropbox\Client;

$key = 'your key dropbox'; //insira seu generated access token do Dropbox

$client = new Client($key); //instanciando um client do Dropbox

$client->createFolder( $_POST['foldername']); //cria a pasta Teste

print_r($client->listFolder('Teste')); //lista o conteúdo da pasta Teste

echo '<br/><br/>'; //apenas para quebrar linha

$client->copy('Coisas', 'Teste1'); //copia o conteúdo da pasta Coisas para a pasta Teste1

print_r($client->listFolder('Teste1')); //lista o conteúdo da pasta Teste1

echo '<br/><br/>'; //apenas para quebrar linha

$client->delete('Teste1/Book.xlsx'); //deleta o arquivo Book.xlsx na pasta Teste1

print_r($client->listFolder('Teste1')); //lista o conteúdo da pasta Teste1

echo '<br/><br/>'; //apenas para quebrar linha
?>
```

Comment: & have you ran that command in your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error output, you're getting a `from_lookup/not_found` error from [/2/files/copy_v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-copy), which means:

> **`from_lookup`** *LookupError*
>
> **`not_found`** *`Void`* There is nothing at the given path.

You'll need to correct the value you're passing as the `from_path` parameter to match an existing item in the connected account/root.

Comment: the code gets the value of a input text to create a dropbox folder